Application of Tychonoffs Theorem
I am currently working on a paper regarding tychonoffs product theorem. At the end of the paper I want to write about some not so known applications of tychonoffs theorem. What I have found so far are the typical results regarding functional analysis (e.g. Banach-Alaoglu) or topology-related (equivalence of axiom of choice and T-Theorem), which I do not want to address.
I have found a nice result about coloring and graph theory using Tychonoffs theorem for a short proof, which I included in the paper. Is there any algebraic or geometric result where Tychonoffs-Theorem is used? Or does anybody know some nice consequences or applications of tychonoffs theorem?

One important application is in logic, where it's called the "compactness theorem": a set of first-order sentences has a model iff every finite subset of it has a model.

Ok thanks! I will look into that
